# Two applications with the same sharedUserId clear the storage during installation

Tags: android, shared-memory

There are two applications with the same sharedUserId. Install the first one, register in it, save the data to SecurePreferences. Install the second application, it erases all the data of the first application. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Since `sharedUserId` is deprecated in Android Q, and since `sharedUserId` will no longer be honored in future versions of Android, perhaps you should stop using `sharedUserId`.

Comment: @CommonsWare What is the alternative? I used it to store the encryption keys that my applications accessed. Applications sent encrypted messages to each other using universal link.

Comment: I am uncertain why you are encrypting communications between two apps on the same device, and what "universal link" means. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sharedUserId): "Instead, proper communication mechanisms such as services and providers should be used to facilitate interoperability between shared components".